# Multiple sheets export from Excel to XML

Tags: xml, excel, export

Is it possible to export multiple same structured sheets FROM Excel to one single XML File?

One single sheet export works fine: (http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/xml.html)

Comment: I took measurements of multiple GPS-devices.
For each record I created an Excel worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy each of your current sheets into a new sheet (one on top of the other).  Then export the new sheet using the common schema.

Comment: After hours of searching this was the best way to solve the problem.